# Learning the entire night of one's 20th Birthday?

Tags: halacha, minhag, torah-study

What is the source for this?
Is there an inyan to do this?

I'm quite new and as you can probably tell, I'm turning 20 in little under a week from now. Not sure what I should really do...

Comment: No need for doubts: you should learn every night of your life, including that of your 20th birthday.

Comment: Welcome. I recommend http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask for details on how to ask a good-quality question that will allow people to answer whatever it is you're really seeking to know.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, and [יום הולדת שמח](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%93%D7%AA_%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%97)! Are you asking about the custom among some people to stay up all that night studying Torah? See this [Hebrew Wikipedia article](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9C_%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%A4%D7%97) that mentions a source for this custom, as well as other sources that the practice is not necessary and that being well-rested to study the following day takes priority.

Comment: In light of your imminent birthday, you may also be interested in the following Mi Yodeya posts that have some relevance to your age: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8629, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3738, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/44339, and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1883.